# th:classappend for appending more than one class

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a scenario that if a condition is equal to particular value i need to append two classes. I was trying using th:classappend and didn't work. This is what i have tried,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" th:classappend="${test.flg== 'A'} ? btn-success anchorDisable : btn-default" >ON</button>
```

In the above code, if flag == 'A' i need to append these two classes btn-success, anchorDisable. Can anyone take a look on my code and help me to solve this. Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding a single quote around the classes? Eg: `'btn-success anchorDisable'`

Comment: let me try that

Comment: @Lucky Thanks a lot that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enclose the classes with single quotes in the expression.

Eg:

```
th:classappend="${test.flg== 'A'} ? 'btn-success anchorDisable' : 'btn-default' "
```